# Java seems to be sending carriage returns to a sub-process?

Tags: java, windows, vbscript, process, stream

I am using Java to handle the overhead of running a sub-process. The sub-process is the Microsoft Compute Cluster Pack (if that is relevant). When I run the MSCCP on command-line, everything is fine, I interact with it in prompts and everyone is happy. When I try to do the same in Java, the sub-process seems to act like infinite carriage returns are being sent to its stdin. (When I run the process on command prompt and just hit carriage return over and over, it exhibits the same behavior as when I run it in Java). Here is my java code, pretty standard:

```
List<String> params =
    Arrays.asList("cmd.exe", "/c", "job.cmd", "submit", stderr, stdout, cwd, scheduler, name, user, run, bif);

final Process p = new ProcessBuilder(params).redirectErrorStream(true).directory(location).start();
```

To keep the question concise, assume all variables are set right. They are -- I ran a loop, println-ing them to console, then copy and pasted them directly into my command prompt and it runs. Other variables, such as `write` below are BlockingQueues. In separate threads, I am listening to the stdout/err and stdin:

```
// Thread for writing to sub-process' input stream when Queue has char[] in it
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    char[] writeThis;
    PrintWriter procIn = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(), true);
    try { //write is a BlockingQueue which contains input to the program.
      while ((writeThis = write.take()) != null) {
        wait.set(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < writeThis.length; i++) {
          procIn.print(writeThis[i]);
          writeThis[i] = 0; //clearing buffer for security reasons.
        }
        procIn.println(); //the only carriage return I intend to send...
        wait.set(false);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}).start();

// Thread for listening to the stdout/stderr of the sub-process and reacting to its output.
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Scanner procOut = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
    StringBuffer reqs = new StringBuffer();
    while (procOut.hasNext()) {
      String str = procOut.next() + " ";
      reqs.append(str);
      if (reqs.toString().startsWith("Enter the password for")) {
        // do stuff...
      } else if (str.contains(")")) {
        // do stuff...
      }
      pauseTillWaitFalse();
    }
  }
}).start();
```

What I notice is that the output of the process (`procOut` above) shoots output as if a carriage return were continually being sent to the `job.cmd` sub-process. The commands I do wish to send out in `procIn` do not get sent at all! Its as if the `procIn` goes to NUL or something.

Somethings to note about `job.cmd` it is a file which internally calls a VB script which is actually running the sub-process. `@%windir%\system32\cscript.exe //Nologo "%~dp0%~n0.vbs" %*` Where job.vbs is what is being run.

Again, this all runs completely fine when in command prompt. I do not understand why running it with the Java Process API would be any different unless the Command Prompt is issuing some kind of stability commands in the background to keep `job.vbs` happy?

EDIT: Just to quell any possible confusion, the input arguments stdout, stderr have nothing to do with the Process standard out/in. They have to do with something else specific to the job.cmd system.

UPDATE:
I found where in the vb code is asks for the password. There is a section that goes as such:

```
 Set objPassword = CreateObject("ScriptPW.Password")         
 if IsObject(objPassword)=false then            
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "Not support password to be * or empty on Vista or Longhorn."              
    WScript.Quit(1)         
 end if
```

So it appears the `ScriptPW.Password` feature of VB is not playing nice with Java. Is there any way around this? (I still would rather use this as a method of transmitting the password).

Comment: Perhaps the subprocess is ignoring the standard input stream and trying to read directly from the console?

Comment: @HarryJohnston how can I ensure it is not ignoring the stdin? Also, why would it ignore stdin when called from the JVM and not from the windows shell?

Comment: If my guess is correct, then the subprocess is ignoring standard input in both cases.  The easiest way to test this would be to run `job.cmd < testfile` from the command prompt.  If the contents of `testfile` are read successfully, then my guess was wrong.

Comment: You are right. When I type in the command job.cmd > testfile the output does not go into testfile it is displayed in the cmd prompt. So... what can we do? -- (Is there a way to force a program to listen to stdin, output to stdout?)

Comment: The output and input are independent, so `job.cmd > testfile` doesn't really prove much.  For one thing, it might just mean the process is writing to standard error.  Did you try `job.cmd < testfile` as suggested?

Comment: No, there's no way to force a command-line process to use the standard handles instead of the console, any more than you can force a GUI process to use standard handles instead of presenting a GUI.  If my guess was correct, you need to look for other ways of controlling MSCPP - for example, you might be able to provide all the input in the command-line arguments, or perhaps there's a COM interface or a DLL you can use.

Comment: both `job.cmd > testfile` and `job.cmd < testfile` do the same thing -- nothing (at least to the testfile). What is bugging me is this: How come I can run `job.cmd` on the command-prompt and it will accept my responses via the console but I can't do the equivalent thing when running through a java sub process? What is command prompt doing in the background that is stabilizing `job.cmd`?

Comment: If my guess is correct, then it is reading directly from its default console.  When you run it from the command prompt, its default console is the command prompt's console, so it works.  When you run it from Java, I suspect that it doesn't have a default console at all, and that's why it doesn't work.  On the other hand, I'd have expected a new console to have been automatically created when the VB script launched the executable, so perhaps something else is happening.

Comment: What happens if you change `cscript` to `wscript` in `job.cmd` and then run `job.cmd` from the console?

Comment: I've spent some time playing with cscript //.. options as well as wscript. Neither are working with Java though. Can you recommend any options maybe, or different script.exe type programs that can run the job.vbs? (This seems like a promising lead!)

Comment: From what you've said, `job.cmd` works (using `cscript`) when you run it from the command prompt.  What I'm asking is whether it keeps working if you change it to use `wscript` instead, and how the behaviour changes.  It should either not work at all, or pop up a new console and prompt for input there; I'd like to know which.

Comment: SWEET! I got it to work! Well not the input/outstream parts. I utilized the cscript //X debug mode to go into the vbs file, line by line and found there is a /password:".." option that isn't in the documentation. When I put my password into there manually, it runs :)

Comment: To answer your question, it just didn't work at all.

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand quite what you're doing that requires you to reenter your password, but it does appear clear now that Java is not part of the problem - you can replicate the same issue without Java being involved at all.  It might be worth seeing if you can launch MSCPP directly from Java without the command script and vbscript as part of the picture.